# Repeated capture group inside particular xml tags

Tags: regex

Yes, I know, I shouldn't be using regex for xml, but I need to, and it's only a practice to learn more about regex.

I want to capture all the xml attributes, but only inside a particular tag.

Tag "a" in this case.

Here you can see what I was trying:
https://regex101.com/r/qZGjbL/1

This is the regex I'm using

```
="\s*([^"]*)"[\s|>|\/]
```

It selects all attributes in my xml, but I don't know how to limit it to only apply inside my "a" tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eg. Input:

```
<a>
    <iden asd="foo" bde="thing"> <bla bla="blabla"/> 
</a> 
<b>
    <iden asd="foo" bde="thing"> <bla bla="blabla"/>  
</b>
```

First find the contents of the tags you're interested in. [([\W\w]*?)</a>](https://regex101.com/r/qZGjbL/2)

```
<iden asd="foo" bde="thing"> <bla bla="blabla"/>
```

Then find the attributes within that content. [="\s*([^"]*)"[\s|>|/]](https://regex101.com/r/qZGjbL/1)

```
foo
thing
blabla
```

Comment: So, it can't be done in one regex? does it have a high impact on performance?

Comment: A select few languages make it so you can do this in one regex, but with plain old regex, you'll need two. All regex can do is look for the same pattern over and over again, so that's just how you need to think about it.

Comment: It shouldn't affect performance more than a regex that combines the two; all you have is the overhead of running another regex which is super-minimal.